# Async SQLAlchemy Session: Commit using AsyncSession() or AsyncSession?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio

I am starting to use `AsyncSession` from `sqlalchemy` in a `asyncio` app. However, when assigning an `AsyncSession` object to a class like `Foo` ([based on official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-asyncio-scoped-session)) and `Bar` below, is there any difference between doing it in the following 2 ways?

```
from asyncio import current_task

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

async_session_factory = sessionmaker(some_async_engine, class_=_AsyncSession)
AsyncSession = async_scoped_session(async_session_factory, scopefunc=current_task)


class Foo:
    # https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#using-asyncio-scoped-session
    async def start(self):
        self.async_session = AsyncSession()

    async def some_function(self, some_object):
        # use the AsyncSession directly
        self.async_session.add(some_object)

        # use the AsyncSession via the context-local proxy
        await AsyncSession.commit()

        # "remove" the current proxied AsyncSession for the local context
        await AsyncSession.remove()

class Bar:
    async def start(self):
        self.async_session = AsyncSession()

    async def some_function(self, some_object):
        self.async_session.add(some_object)
        await self.async_session.commit()
```

I am using the method similar to in `Bar` elsewhere and kept getting the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.UniqueViolationError'>: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "scores_pkey"
```

When I try `Foo`, I get the error:

```
    await AsyncSession.remove()
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: in your `Bar` example, it sounds like you are calling the commit multiple times, in my experience with the `AsyncSession` whenever I call `commit()` multiple times, the commit needs to be coupled with a `begin()` right after it